# Ethernet from computer

Tags: raspbian, ethernet

How can I make my Windows 10 give out an Ethernet connection to my Raspberry Pi, and what do I have to do in my raspberry pi's files?

P.S. I don't know where else to put it, mods, please direct me to a better place if there is one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Internet Connection from Windows 7 to RPi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/share-internet-connection-from-windows-7-to-rpi)

Comment: If you are using a recent (May 2015 or later) Raspbian you shouldn't have to do anything on the Pi. (Indeed changing settings is more likely to stop the automatic process working.) I don't have Windows 10, but the process should be similar to others. All you have to do is enable Internet Connection Sharing on Windows and plug the Pi into an Ethernet port. You don't even need a crossover cable.

Comment: @Milliways I did that, and it didn't work. Maybe there is something else?

Comment: @pastacool I will try the top answer for that question later :P

Comment: The answers @pastacool linked to are very old, and will not work with current Raspbian (without major configuration changes). You may be better asking about ICS on a Windows forum. You should be able to get ICS working without static IP.

Comment: You need to clarify. The comments suggest internet (connection and sharing) while the original post itself just speaks about ethernet. Please mind the difference and edit the question to clarify. You might also want to follow Milliway's last advice and read up on ICS if internet sharing on the windows pc is what you want.